# Is it possible to override Local Storage and Session Storage separately in HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, session-storage

I know it's possible to override the HTML5 storage APIs by overriding Storage.prototype.getItem, setItem, removeItem and clear. But that will override those methods for both local storage *and* session storage.

Is it possible to just override one and not the other? Or to override both separately?

A little context: I have an existing app that makes very heavy use of both local storage and session storage. I want to add some temporary code to mirror the stuff in local storage in another storage mechanism, but I don't want to drag the session storage contents along with it.

I could update every reference to localStorage to call some wrapper function that could do the mirroring, but I really don't want to update all those calls. It would be way cleaner if I could localize this code by overriding a single set of storage methods.

Comment: I'm not sure but the fact that you are trying to override them at all is disturbing.

Comment: I added some context to the question. Independent of all that, I'm also just genuinely curious :)

Comment: Another reason could be privacy concerns (think of GDPR cookie consent banners). As local storage is comparable to cookies. If a user opts-out of all cookies then in this case I want all calls to localStorage.setItem() to do nothing. Overriding this methods in a central place might be easier and avoids touching multiple places in your code.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are several possibilities to achieve what you want. But remember, none of them should be used in production environment.

The first option detects if `setItem` method was called by `sessionStorage` or `localStorage` object. You could write it this way:

```
var _setItem = Storage.prototype.setItem;

Storage.prototype.setItem = function(key, value) { 
    if (this === window.localStorage) {
         // do what you want if setItem is called on localStorage
    } else {
         // fallback to default action
         _setItem.apply(this, arguments);
    }
}
```

The second one, replaces prototype of `sessionStorage` or `localStorage` object. It may look like this:

```
localStorage.__proto__ = Object.create(Storage.prototype);
localStorage.__proto__.setItem = function() {
    // your logic here
}
```

Notice, that I used `__proto__` pseudo property which is non-standard, but exposed in Chrome and Firefox. (Don't know about Opera, Safari and others). However, as you can see it might be helpful during development.

Comment: That first option is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Why shouldn't they be used in productive environments?

Comment: @Zim84 Because they are unreliable hacks on the native objects, and they might break from one browser version to the next

Answer (score -3):

Yes, Local Storage and Session Storage override separately in HTML5

```
localStorage.setItem('name', Krishna); //here local storege value is Krishna
sessionStorage.name = "Krishna"; //here Session storege value is Krishna
```

In below we override Local Storage and Session Storage value separately

```
localStorage.setItem('name', Sri); //here local storege value is Sri
sessionStorage.name = "Pal"; //here Session storege value is Pal
```

Comment: you have answered a totally different question