# is it possible to override "sessionStorage" setItem and getItem functions in angular 4?

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to encrypt my data always before setting to *sessionStorage*  and decrypt after reading form it. Is it possible to override this functions or is there any other solution for this issue.

I don't want to do the encryption and decryption on all codes that I've written before ...

for example:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('token', 'my token');
```

in the code above, I want the *sessionStorage.setItem* function to do the encryption on *'my token'*.

I know how to encrypt it but I want to implement it in *sessionStorage.setItem* function.

any help will be appreciated ...

Comment: Looking for something like this? It can be used in Angular aswell
[Override Local and SessionStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13612643/is-it-possible-to-override-local-storage-and-session-storage-separately-in-html5?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Instead of modifying the prototype of a native API (which is considered a bad practice) you could use https://github.com/localForage/localForage package