# Local storage setItem override - Illegal invocation error

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to override the `localStorage.setItem` method to add a disable local storage option for debugging purpose. But I keep having a Illegal Invocation error when using the method.

```js
let originalFunction = window.Storage.prototype.setItem;
window.Storage.prototype.setItem = (keyName, keyValue) => {
    console.log("Override worked ! ")
    let currentState = localStorage.getItem("disableStorage");
    if (currentState === null || keyName === "disableStorage") {
        originalFunction(keyName, keyValue);
    }
    return;
}
localStorage.setItem("test", "blah");
```

I've done a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/polypode/n4t9zpLa/1/) for you to test it, as in the code snippet, local storage won't work.

I've tried with and without window, it won't work either case.

We can't see it correctly in the jsfiddle but the error is at the line : `originalFunction(keyName, keyValue)`

I've done the override corresponding to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5409468/12159514). But it doesn't seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem.
Apparently, we need to use `.apply` to call the original method.

I've updated the fiddle, so it's the working version now. Here's a snippets for coherence :

```js
let originalFunction = window.Storage.prototype.setItem;
window.Storage.prototype.setItem = function(keyName, keyValue) {
    console.log("Override worked ! ")
    let currentState = localStorage.getItem("disableStorage");
    if (currentState === null || keyName === "disableStorage") {
        originalFunction.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    return;
}
localStorage.setItem("test", "blah");
```

The snippet won't work but the code does.

I've found the synthax [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13613729/12159514).

Comment: Just be aware that you've overwritten the Storage method, but coupled this to the `localStorage` instance. If you want to override `sessionStorage` behaviour too, then you should change to `this.getItem`. If you only want to affect `localStorage`, then you should just override `localStorage.setItem`.